# Sonar scanner issue in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I am trying to integrate sonar with Jenkins in my local, when integrating the build   is successfully and execution is success, but it is not getting finished success, it show below error and it show out of memory

```
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/al-config-server
            INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
            INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWWunlqCAbj3m24yQM89
            INFO: Task total time: 6.254 s
            INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
            INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            INFO: Total time: 8.008s
            INFO: Final Memory: 57M/313M
            INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
            Recursion Count=593, Stack Usage=90 percent
            ******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
            WARN: Found multiple 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Taking the first one.
            C:\Users\sreenath.reddy\.jenkins\workspace\al-config-server\.scannerwork\report-task.txt
            C:\Users\sreenath.reddy\.jenkins\workspace\al-config-server\target\sonar\report-task.txt
            WARN: Found multiple 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Taking the first one.
            C:\Users\sreenath.reddy\.jenkins\workspace\al-config-server\.scannerwork\report-task.txt
            C:\Users\sreenath.reddy\.jenkins\workspace\al-config-server\target\sonar\report-task.txt
            ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 255
            Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916823/batch-limitation-maximum-recursion-while-browsing-menus/11917798#11917798). How do you start the analysis?

Comment: Hi @JeroenHeier I tried but the Sonar scanner is running successful but after that it is getting failed.