# When running Hive on Windows 10 getting error as "Batch Recursion Exceeded"

Tags: batch-file, hadoop, hive

I have installed Hadoop single node cluster on windows 10 and all components are working absolutely fine. Now I have installed hive and tried to open hive, I got the error as "Batch Recursion Exceeded"

```
C:\hive\bin>hive
******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=339, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Not sure why there are no comments or answers yet, but I suppose we need to see the actual code. This however happens when you have exceeded the maximum number of call recursions. It will happen in a simple batch-file like `:label` and next line `call :label` I could write an answer, but I cannot without seeing the hive script. Anyway, Here is a thread that explains it well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916823/batch-limitation-maximum-recursion-while-browsing-menus/11917798#11917798

Comment: the error can be reproduced by executing a one-line batch file `@call %~0`